# If the quotient of limits converge to 0 then there exists $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge M$, $y_n > |x_n|$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are sequences (not necessarily convergent) such that $y_n > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n} = 0$$ Prove that there exists an $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge M $, $y_n > |x_n|$.

I think for this proof I need to find some value $\epsilon$ that would make the statement true for $M$. But I am stuck on picking a value for $\epsilon$ to make the proof works.

Comment: You could leave epsilon "T.B.D" (to be determined), and go to the definition of $\lim(\cdot)=0.$

Comment: Don't bother about $M$ (it will be given by the limit in the hypothesis). Apply the definition of that limit to some $\epsilon$ such that $|x_n/y_n|<\epsilon\Rightarrow y_n>|x_n|$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

What is the definition of convergence for sequences?

Here it is the particular case we are interested in:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |a_{n} - 0| < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}

In the present case, it suffices to consider $a_{n} = x_{n}/y_{n}$ and $\varepsilon = 1$.

Can you take it from here?